# Public REST API Authentication and Authorization using AWS Cognito

Tags: rest, jwt, amazon-cognito

I'm developing a REST API that will be accessed by customers, and I'd like to use AWS Cognito to handle authentication and authorization.

However, I want to abstract AWS Cognito from my customers, so that if I change from AWS Cognito to a different service, they don't have to change their code (just the API Key).

Unfortunately, after many **days** reading AWS's documentation, I couldn't find an answer to the following:

> How can I give my clients a "[personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new)" that never expires, that they can use to authenticate their scripts and back-end services, similar to what you can use for authenticating with GitHub?

So far, I created a REST Endpoint where clients can POST their `username` and `password` and I *talk* to AWS Cognito on their behalf, to do the authentication:

```
var request = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest
{
    UserPoolId = "MyUserPoolId",
    ClientId = "MyUserPoolAppClientId",
    AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH,
};

request.AuthParameters.Add("USERNAME", "myuser@mydomain.com");
request.AuthParameters.Add("PASSWORD", "123456"); // Relax, this is demo code

string accessToken = string.Empty;
var response = await _identityProvider.AdminInitiateAuthAsync(request);
var authResult = response.AuthenticationResult;
```

This all works, and `authResult` gives me 3 tokens that (I think) expire after 30 days (which I can configure up to 3650 days maximum).

This gives me 3 tokens (Access, ID, Refresh). I feel like giving these 3 tokens to the caller would be a bad choice as it's Cognito-specific...

How can I give my customers an API Key, that I can then use to authenticate them with Cognito?

Comment: I am stuck with a similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59454833/aws-cognito-user-pool-server-side-flow-with-spring-boot. I don't think an API key ever longing exists in cognito, only way is by user and password auth. How did you handle response to auth challenge ? is it safe to get user, password of the customer through an API and pass it to aws cognito again to get the token ?